# What does the pound sign mean in Idris 2?

Tags: dependent-type, idris2, linear-types

I am browsing through the standard library of Idris 2 and I stumbled upon this:

[Data.Linear.Array](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/f694e5e2f0ceb38e9487fc59157f2e545c08eed4/libs/contrib/Data/Linear/Array.idr#L49):

```
export
MArray LinArray where
  newArray size k = k (MkLinArray (unsafePerformIO (newArray size)))

  write (MkLinArray a) i el
      = unsafePerformIO (do ok <- writeArray a i el
                            pure (ok # MkLinArray a))
  msize (MkLinArray a) = max a # MkLinArray a
  mread (MkLinArray a) i
      = unsafePerformIO (readArray a i) # MkLinArray a
```

What does the pound sign mean?

The REPL reports:

```
Main> :t (#)
Builtin.(#) : (1 _ : a) -> (1 _ : b) -> LPair a b
Builtin.DPair.(#) : (val : a) -> (1 _ : t val) -> Res a t
```

So I suppose it is related to linear pairs. How are linear pairs used with linear arrays?